# ajax: does an inner done-callback consistently fire before an outer one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, deferred

when using your own asynchronous function, you can have multiple `.done()`-handlers:

```
function callAjax()
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: "my_url.json",
        dataType: "json",
        method: "GET"
    })
    .done(function(){
        console.log("inner done called back");
    });
}

callAjax().done(function(){
    console.log("outer done called back");
});
```

when testing the inner callback always fired before the outer one.

**my question is:** is this a guaranteed behavior? can I rely on this?

Comment: Yes, until and unless `promise` isn't returned from the called function i.e. `ajax` here, the outer callback wouldn't fire..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao and the inner callback still would fire when the `promise` isn't returned?

Comment: Inner callback will fire once `ajax` call is `done` and once inner `done` is executed, that promise will be returned to the outer `callback`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao ok, thank you very much! and where have you got this information from, if I may ask you kindly?

Comment: Well, long back I have read and that's how I have been working with callbacks since then.. I don't know from where I can get the link now.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao ok, then I just have to trust you so far ;) if you want to then please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Its ok buddy.. Since I do not have hard material to keep a proof, I do not want to post it as a answer.. Let me see if I can get an working example and then post it as answer..